# Any way to have wildcards in fstab?

Tags: linux, mount, cifs, wildcard, fstab

My goal is to allow any user to mount a cifs share to /media/networkshare or even better /media/networkshare/share_*

Is there any way to allow wildcards in fstab such that they can do that?  I can't predefine the share location.

Is there any way to make an fstab entry like this?  I'd like for them to be able to set any option or source on their own.

Comment: This sounds more like a job for autofs and/or a helper script in .bashrc that will look for conditions that meet your criteria and mount based on them.

Comment: How would a helper script work any differently than what the user can do manually?  (and if I'm reading how to do cifs with autofs right, I'd still need to know the share ahead of time to define it)

Comment: Too late to edit that last comment, but so far the only solution I've found unless I can use wildcards for fstab is to allow sudo for any user for /usr/sbin/mount.cifs